# Color Code MatLab Histogram Based on a Condition of a 2x2 Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, signals

if I have a 2x2 Matrix such as

```
1 2
4 7
```

And I want to plot a histogram based on the condition that the diagonals should be the color green, and everything else except the diagonals should be red, how do I do that in Matlab.

I have tried separating the 2x2 matrix into two different vectors representing the diagonal and the others (except diagonals), but when I do:

```
hist(diagonals)
hist(others)
```

It doesn't really work and seems to just randomly color code things into one histogram (I do want just the one histogram though.) How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What is a histogram based on a condition? Are you just counting the number of pixels that meet that condition? How are you detecting green or red from scalar values? What color is '7'? Why are you taking a histogram of a 2x2 matrix? I understand all of the words you use in the question, but the way they're put together makes no sense to me. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: So, in this 2x2 matrix I want to somehow overlay in different colours the frequency of the values. So, each bar of the histogram in the diagonal (i.e. 1/7) should be the colour green, the rest of the bars should be red. This means somehow overlaying a bar on another bar. For example, say I have 7 instead of 2, then I'd have to somehow show that it had one value that was red/ the other green. Honestly, I think this sort of data I want to represent is better suited to a scatter plot but my supervisor wants a histogram

Comment: @Display I have absolutely no idea what it is you're asking.  Would it be possible for you to actually draw out a real example?  You don't need code as I'm not even sure where I'd begin to implement.  Please illustrate with an actual graphical example.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't explain it very well. I did manage to find a solution, which I'll post

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem, using `hold on` fixes this issue

```
histogram(diagonals, 'FaceColor', 'g')
hold on
histogram(others, 'FaceColor', 'r')
hold on
```